# Use Rcpp function in foreach %dopar%

Tags: r, foreach, rcpp

I have created an Rcpp test package called "test" using the Rcpp package skeleton to try to run c++ code in parallel but keep running into errors. I'm running R 4.1.2 on Mac OS and have updated all parallel computing packages. I added to the package skeleton an R script containing

```
# wrap c++ function in R function
test_func <- function()
{
  return(rcpp_hello_world())
}

# attempt to parallelize
parallelize <- function()
{
  
  # create cluster
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() - 1)
  parallel::clusterExport(cl,varlist = c("test_func","rcpp_hello_world"),envir = environment())
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

  # call test_func in parallel
  res <- foreach::`%dopar%`(foreach::foreach(i = 1:5,.combine = c),ex = {test_func()})
  
  # clean up
  parallel::stopCluster(cl)

  return(res)
  
}
```

I loaded my package using `devtools::load_all()`, but typing `parallelize()` in my console I get the error "Error in { : task 1 failed - "object '_test_rcpp_hello_world' not found" ". When I add "_test_rcpp_hello_world" to the clusterExport call I get the error "Error in { : task 1 failed - "NULL value passed as symbol address" ".

Everything works fine when I switch `%dopar%` to `%do%`, but I'm hoping to be able to still parallelize.

I know that similar questions have been asked here, but I can't use a solution which calls sourceCpp on each worker (the c++ code in my actual R package is huge and this operation would defeat the purpose of parallelizing).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This is an old and trusted topic and I am fairly certain there duplicates but I don't have time to search now. In short, put your code in a package, have the package loaded on each node -- then it will have the code.  _Locally built code_ is local to a random memory location in your RAM and only the _reference_ to it gets to the nodes.  A package ensures a node has the compiled code.

Comment: Then I would need to develop a second package which calls my actual package.. do you know of a way to self export a package to foreach like what you are describing? I tried ```.packages = c("test")``` in my foreach call but it didn't work.

Comment: I think you are reasonably close but you _cannot_ send local function over. You can however ask for a node a) load a package and b) then send the request to run a function with the parameters neeeded.  There are examples for 'distribute compute and use packages in nodes', so keep digging at existing documentation.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thank you for clarifying I haven't seen that said explicitly anywhere else!

Answer (score 1):

(Continuing from the comments)

The key is that to execute 'local' code on a node, you cannot send a (compiled) function to the node.  The node needs to have it, and the best way it to have the node(s) have access to the same package(s), load them and thus be ready to run code using them.  I just glanced at some old [slide decks from presentations I gave](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/presentations.html) and I didn't find an perfect example -- but a pointer to a (thirteen-plus (!!) year old) directory of example scripts including this for running (cpu-wise expensive) DieHarder tests on nodes via Rmpi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env r

suppressMessages(library(Rmpi))
suppressMessages(library(snow))

cl <- NULL
mpirank <- mpi.comm.rank(0)
if (mpirank == 0) {
    cl <- makeMPIcluster()
} else {                          # or are we a slave?
    sink(file="/dev/null")
    slaveLoop(makeMPImaster())
    mpi.finalize()
    q()
}

clusterEvalQ(cl, library(RDieHarder))
res <- parLapply(cl, c("mt19937","mt19937_1999",
           "mt19937_1998", "R_mersenne_twister"),
         function(x) {
                 dieharder(rng=x, test="operm5",
                           psamples=100, seed=12345)
                     })
stopCluster(cl)

print( do.call(rbind, lapply(res, function(x) { x[[1]] } )))

mpi.quit()
```

The key is in the middle: `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(RDieHarder))`  All worker nodes are asked to load the [RDieHarder](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=RDieHarder) package.  Conceptually, you want to do the same here, and the `foreach` family lets you do it too.